# How to access call parameters and arguments with __getattr__

Tags: python, arguments, callable, getattr

I have the following code, where most of the code seem to look awkward, confusing and/or circumstantial, but most of it is to demonstrate the parts of the much larger code where I have a problem with. Please read carefully

```
# The following part is just to demonstrate the behavior AND CANNOT BE CHANGED UNDER NO CIRCUMSTANCES
# Just define something so you can access something like derived.obj.foo(x)
class Basic(object):
    def foo(self, x=10):
        return x*x

class Derived(object):
    def info(self, x):
        return "Info of Derived: "+str(x) 
    def set(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

# The following piece of code might be changed, but I would rather not
class DeviceProxy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # just to set up something that somewhat behaves as the real code in question
        self.proxy = Derived()
        self.proxy.set(Basic())

    # crucial part: I want any attributes forwarded to the proxy object here, without knowing beforehand what the names will be
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.proxy, attr)

# ======================================
# This code is the only I want to change to get things work

# Original __getattr__ function
original = DeviceProxy.__getattr__

# wrapper for the __getattr__ function to log/print out any attribute/parameter/argument/...
def mygetattr(device, key):
    attr = original(device, key) 
    if callable(attr):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            print('%r called with %r and %r' % (attr, args, kw))
            return attr(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper
    else:  
        print "not callable: ", attr
        return attr

DeviceProxy.__getattr__ = mygetattr


# make an instance of the DeviceProxy class and call the double-dotted function
dev = DeviceProxy()
print dev.info(1)
print dev.obj.foo(3)
```

What I want is to catch all method calls to `DeviceProxy` to be able to print all arguments/parameters and so on. In the given example, this works great when calling `info(1)`, all of the information is printed. 
But when I call the double-dotted function `dev.obj.foo(3)`, I only get the message that this is not a callable.

How can I modify the above code so I also get my information in the second case? Only the code below the `===` can be modified.

Comment: The problem is that for `dev.obj.foo(3)`, `mygetattr` is being called with device `dev` and key `obj`, which is indeed not callable. What you need is to figure out a way to call it with device `obj` and key `foo`. (How to do that isn't readily apparent to me.)

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem. It seems I need another layer of wrapper or something like that, but I do not know for sure how many there are. There could be calls like `device.service.info.version.firmware` or whatever.

Comment: As far as I can tell, "Basic" and "Derived" are not using inheritance, despite the names.

Answer (score 3):

You have just a `__getattr__` on `dev` and you want, from within this `__getattr__`, to have access to `foo` when you do `dev.obj.foo`.  This isn't possible.  The attribute accesses are not a "dotted function" that is accessed as a whole.  The sequence of attribute accesses (the dots) is evaluated one at a time, left to right.  At the time that you access `dev.obj`, there is no way to know that you will later access `foo`.  The method `dev.__getattr__` only knows what attributes you are accessing *on `dev`*, not what attributes of that result you may later access.

The only way to achieve what you want would be to also include some wrapping behavior in `obj`.  You say you can't modify the "Base"/"Derived" classes, so you can't do it that way.  You could, in theory, have `DeviceProxy.__getattr__` not return the actual value of the accessed attribute, but instead wrap that object in another proxy and return the proxy.  However, that could get a bit tricky and make your code more difficult to understand and debug, since you could wind up with tons of objects being wrapped in thin proxies.